# Recuperar las publicaciones creadas por un usuario especifico Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Tengo una propiedad $type boolean , para diferenciar mis dos tipos de publicaciones
estoy intentando recuperar las publicaciones de type= true, (que son recetas) de un usuario espécifico para la pagina perfil de usuario.

```
 /**
     * @Route("/profil/{id}", name="profil", methods={"GET","POST"})
     * 
     */
    public function index(User $user): Response
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $publications = $em->getRepository('App:Publication')->findBy(
            array('users' => $user->getId()),
            array('created_at' => 'Desc')
        );

         ****// listar las publicacion de recetas 
         $recette = $em->getRepository('App:Publication')->findBy(['type'=>true],['created_at' => 'desc']);****
        

        // recuperar las 3 ultimas recetas para el sidebar rigth
        $lastRecettes = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Publication::class)->lastXRecette(4);
        // lister les 9 dernières recettes
        $recette = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Publication::class)->lastPRecette(9);      

        return $this->render('profil/index.html.twig', [          
            'publications' => $publications,
            'recettes' => $recette,
            'user' => $user,
            'lastRecettes' => $lastRecettes,
        ]);
    }
```

la parte resaltada me permite recuperar todas las recetas pero no se como agregar el usuario intenté esto pero no es correcto:

```php
$recette = $em->getRepository('App:Publication')->findBy(['type'=>true], ['users' => $user->getId()],['created_at' => 'desc']);
```

Answer (score 0):

te propongo que intentes de esta forma.

```
$recette = $em->getRepository(Publication::class)->findBy(['type'=>true, 'users' => $user->getId()],['created_at' => 'desc']);
```

Los métodos mágicos de **Doctrine** por defecto funcionan con **AND**. Te recomiendo igual que utilices consultas creada con el **QueryBuilder** ya que obtendrás mejor rendimiento si solo solicitas en el `select` y los `addSelect` los campos que necesitas.

La consulta que quieres hacer desde el **QueryBuilder**

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
            return $qb->select('p')
                ->join('p.user','user')
                ->where($qb->expr()->eq('user.id', ':user'))
                ->setParameter('user', $user)
                ->orderBy('p.created_at', 'DESC')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```